# how to show one time toast messages in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, toast, android-toast

I wanted to add a `toast message` when clicked on a button and I added it. Now I want show it only **one time**, that means the toast message will **not show again** if clicked on the button after the first time **also after a restart of app**.
Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `SharedPreferences` that you store in another class like `Utility.java`:

```
public class Utility {

    public static SharedPreferences preferences(Context context) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    public static Boolean hasSendToast(Context context) {
        return preferences(context).getBoolean("Toast", false);
    }

    public static void setSendToast(Context context, Boolean bool) {
        preferences(context).edit()
                .putBoolean("Toast", bool).apply();
    }
}
```

And use it with your `Toast` inside the `onClickListener` in your `MainActivity.java` like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (!Utility.hasSendToast(getApplicationContext())) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "My Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                Utility.setSendToast(getApplicationContext(), true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I created a new activity called **Utility.java** and put your first code lines in there. Then in the **MainActivity** I added that `setOnClickListener` and an intent. Then changed the toast message but the toast message is still showing not stopping.

Comment: I updated my coce. Now it is working :) I forgot to set apply() in Utility. I tested everything and the answer should be correct :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences. After the first click write a boolean into shared preferences to indicate the first click has happened. Next time the user clicks the button make sure to check if that boolean has been set and don't show the toast if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boolean flag and store the value using Shared Preference.

```
btn.onClickListener {
   if(!getToastShownStatusFromSharedPreference()) {
     showToast()
     changeToastShowsStatusToSharedPreference()
   }
   /* other operations */
}
```

Comment: Do I need to add something to the lines like `Toast.makeText` except `/* other operations */`

Comment: Yes, that is the way if you want to show toast message.
`Toast.makeText(context, toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that with **SharedPreferences** which is a pref manager in android. You can follow the below process:

1. Declare a boolean as like `isFirstTime = true`.
2. On the click of the button check boolean status, and if its true then fire the toast message and make `isFirstTime = false`.

That's it.